# Google app engine user service

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Hello guys. I created a simple datastorage with Google App engine datastore java. All users can see the same data after log in, how can I ensure each user to access only his own data after log in?

Please, any site for tutorial will be also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which user has access to which data is entirely dependent on your application code that processes a web request, talks to the data store, and outputs an HTML response. If you post more specifics about your app, I can be more helpful.

The GAE docs are quite helpful: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested by the solution to this problem when the user is logging through Gmail, using `UserService`.